# What structure should I use to get a user with the highest score

Tags: redis

In a certain game, users keep scoring points. How do I maintain this in redis?

Scoring pattern is as follows

```
u1, 1
u2, 1
u1, 1
u3, 1
u4, 1
u5, 1
u4, 1
u4, 1
u1, 1
u4, 1
u2, 1
```

I would want redis to return and I want the results to auto sort by the leader every time we put into a structure in redis.

```
u4, 4
u1, 3
u2, 2
u3, 1
u5, 1
```

How should I get/put/retrieve via redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build something like a user score, use a sorted set (also called zset), which holds a score next to the data. 
You will be able to retrieve the users in order or reverse order if needed. See the full documentation of commands here: http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set

Comment: Can you show me the exact set of commands, which I should use and for fetching the final set. Is zset deprecated?

Comment: I am still unable to get it to work using the ZADD, ZRANGE commands to sort.

Comment: To add a user to a sorted set use a command like this :` zadd users 4 u1`. This will add an item (user) called u1 with score 4 to the zset ùsers`. To retrieve the users with scores from highest to lowest do this: `zrevrange users 0 -1`This will retrieve all users in descending order. If you need the scores as well add the parameter `WITHSCORES`, like this: `zrevrange users 0 -1 WITHSCORES`